# Sublime Text Markdown-to-HTML-email

Tags: python, macos, email, sublimetext3

I'm loving that I can use [Editorial](http://omz-software.com/editorial/) (iOS) to compose an email in Markdown and pipe a rendered HTML message straight to Mail.app. I'd love to do this with Sublime Text 3 and Sparrow (or any default mail client) on the Mac, and I'm wondering whether it will be possible (or sensible) for me to make a Sublime package or build script.

The only problem is that I don't know Python. I'm not looking for *the final solution*, just whether my plan of using Python is a reasonable one given that I'd like to actually get this working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a pretty cool idea actually.

- Step 1: Get a markdown syntax definition, like: [sublime-markdown-extended](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/sublime-markdown-extended)
- Step 2: Go to "Tools -> Build System -> New Build System" and add your new build:

  ---

  ```
  { 
      "cmd": ["python", "-u", "/path/to/convert.py $file"],
      "selector": "source.markdown",
      "path": "/usr/local/lib/python"
  }
  ```
- Step 3: convert.py uses [markdown2](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2) to create html and opens Mail.app for you:

  ---

  ```
  import sys
  import markdown2

  with open(sys.argv[0]) as f:
      script = 'tell application "Mail"' \
         'make new outgoing message with properties {' \
         'visible:true,content:"%s" }' \
      'end tell' % markdown2.markdown(f.read())

      p = Popen('/usr/bin/osascript',stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE)
      p.communicate(script)
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly specific answer!

Comment: I finally got this working and [posted my progress on my humble blog](http://workingconcept.com/blog/sublime-markdown-to-sparrow-message). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

A nice alternative I started using is the [Markdown Service Tools](http://brettterpstra.com/2013/03/08/new-in-the-markdown-service-tools-in-place-markdown-to-rtf/).

Once installed you will be able to select text in any textbox, choose the Multimarkdown to RTF from the Services menu and have it automatically convert it to Markdown. You can then set a keyboard shortcut to activate it through Preferences :)

Comment: Brett Terpstra to the rescue again! Thanks for the update @dutzi, I've been using Airmail more recently which lets me compose messages in Markdown, but these service tools are useful all over the place.